# A continuous map induced by a continuous map? (Munkres)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm having trouble understanding this exercise from a topology book by Munkres.

The point of the exercise is to prove if $h:S^1 \to S^1$ is antipode-preserving and continuous, then $h$ is not homotopic to a constant map.

> (a) Let $p : S^1 \to S^1$ be the map $p(z) = z^2$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that $h$ **induces a continuous map** $g : S^1 \to S^1$ such that $p \circ h = g \circ p$.
>
> (b) Show that if $f$ is any path in $S^1$ from $x$ to its antipode $-x$ then $p \circ f$ is a loop in $S^1$ that is not path homotopic to a constant.
>
> (c) Show that $p$ and $g$ induce monomorphisms of the fundamental groups.
>
> (d) Conclude $h$ is essential (i.e. not homotopic to a constant map).

Now, I know what the induced homomorphism of a continuous map is. But I don't understand what it means for a continuous map to induce another continuous map with the same domain and codomain.

I was also thinking perhaps it wanted something like $g(e^{i\theta}) = h(e^{i\theta/2})^2$, though I don't see how that fits into the direction of the exercise.

Unfortunately my prof. just distributed this one photocopied page from the book, so perhaps the issue is explained elsewhere that I don't see. Any clarification from someone who is familiar with this book, or has seen this type of construction before, is much appreciated!

Comment: I do not think I understand the exercise, but I would think the "induces" is not used in any technical sense that might have been defined elsewhere. Perhaps the following sentence would have the same meaning: Show that there is a continuous map $g : S^1 \to S^1$ such that $p \circ h = g \circ p$. The word "induces" might perhaps only imply that such a $g$ is unique. Just a guess how to interpret (a).

Answer (score 0):

"induces" in this setting means that there exists a (unique, though this is not very important map such that the diagram

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{ll}
S^1 & \ra{p}& S^1\\
\da{g} & & \da{h}  \\
S^1 & \ra{p} & S^1 \\
\end{array}
$$
commutes.

And as for "one page from the book", you guys do have a library, no?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, we do have a library but it was nothing a summary perusal of the book could turn up - the only indexed use of "induced" is for induced homomorphisms. I'd never heard the word in this context before.